# Codeigniter: Can't seem to get my edit to work

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

So basically I am trying to combine what I found in these two tutorials to make a working CRUD:
http://fwebde.com/php/simple-crud-with-codeigniter/

http://ie.mirror.twsweb-int.com/codeigniter/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Basically, where I am is that I can get the edit page to render the appropriate item details in the form but whenever I press submit, I get a 404 error and the table doesn't get updated.

My edit.php that is tied to my news controller:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<h2>Edit a news item</h2>

<?php echo form_open('news/edit') ?>

<p>
<label for="title">Title</label> 
<?php echo form_input('title',$news_item['title']); ?>
</p>

<p>
<label for="text">Text</label>
<?php echo form_textarea('text',$news_item['text']); ?>
</p>    

<?php echo form_hidden($news_item['id']); ?>

<p>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save Changes'); ?>
</p>

  <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</br>
</br>
<a href='<?php echo site_url('news');?>'>Back</a>
```

My news controller on the edit method:

```
public function edit($slug)
{
    $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

    if (empty($data['news_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Edit: '.$data['news_item']['title'];

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
        $this->load->view('news/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->update_news( $this->input->post('id'),
                                        $this->input->post('title'),
                                        $this->input->post('text'));
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
}
```

Appropriate methods in my model:

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_news()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
}

public function update_news($id, $title, $content) {
    $data = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'content' => $content
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news', $data);
}
```

My routes:

```
$route['news/edit/(:any)'] = 'news/edit/$1';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there were a couple of errors:

1) ifaour's suggestion

2) passing the primary key and slug around as parameters to be used for later

3) forgot I had changed the table column (forgot I had renamed the content column as text)

Model in its final form:

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_news()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
}

public function update_news($id, $title, $content) {
    $data = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'text' => $content
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news', $data);
}
```

Edit in its final form:

```
<h2>Edit a news item</h2>

<a href="<?php echo site_url('news/delete/'.$news_item['id']); ?>">Delete this article</a> 

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/edit/'.$news_item['slug']) ?>

<p>
<label for="title">Title</label> 
<?php echo form_input('title',$news_item['title']); ?>
</p>

<p>
<label for="text">Text</label>
<?php echo form_textarea('text',$news_item['text']); ?>
</p>    

<?php echo form_hidden('slug',$news_item['slug']); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('id',$news_item['id']); ?>

<p>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save Changes'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</br>
</br>
<a href='<?php echo site_url('news');?>'>Back</a>
```

news controller edit method in final form:

```
public function edit($slug)
{
    $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

    if (empty($data['news_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Edit: '.$data['news_item']['title'];

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
        $this->load->view('news/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->update_news( $this->input->post('id'),
                                        $this->input->post('title'),
                                        $this->input->post('text'));


        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);                                   
        $this->load->view('news/success');
        $this->load->view('news/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are submitting the form to the `edit` method which is expecting an item id `$slug`, you can change your view to the following:

```
<?php echo form_open('news/edit/' . $news_item['id']) ?>
```

Comment: Part of my solution but there ended up being more. Thank you for the insight though.